# Drag and drop files in VS Code stopped working

Tags: file, drag-and-drop, location

When manually dragging and dropping files into a new folder has stopped working.
VS Code seems to be unable to find the files after they have been moved.

I checked setting: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2sUE.png)
File/Preferences/Settings/..JavaScript › Update Imports On File Move: Enabled

When I drag and drop I don't get the dialog box to select yes to update the file location.

Version: 1.69.2 (user setup)
Commit: 3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a
Date: 2022-07-18T16:12:52.460Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043